# Apache Kafka Streams - not able to aggreagate with windowing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Simply , I want to calculate Low and High temperature over each minute (1 minute window) , below is my scenario :

There is a incoming temperature information coming each second to a temperature_per_sec_topic kafka topic , below class represents this temp. info.

```
public class Temperature {
    private double temperature;
    private Long timeStamp;

    public Temperature(double temperature, Long timeStamp) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(double temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public Long getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(Long timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

and below class represents Temperature stats per minute :

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class TemperatureStat {

    private Double lowTemp;
    private Double highTemp;
    private Long timeStamp;


    public TemperatureStat() {
    }

    public TemperatureStat(double lowTemp, double highTemp, long timeStamp) {
        this.lowTemp = lowTemp;
        this.highTemp = highTemp;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }



    public double getLowTemp() {
        return lowTemp;
    }

    public void setLowTemp(double lowTemp) {
        this.lowTemp = lowTemp;
    }

    public double getHighTemp() {
        return highTemp;
    }

    public void setHighTemp(double highTemp) {
        this.highTemp = highTemp;
    }

    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public TemperatureStat update(String jsonTemp){
        Temperature temp = new Gson().fromJson(jsonTemp,Temperature.class);
        if(this.highTemp == null) this.highTemp = temp.getTemperature();

        if(temp.getTemperature() > highTemp) highTemp = temp.getTemperature();
        else if(temp.getTemperature() < lowTemp) lowTemp = temp.getTemperature();
        else System.out.print("in between low and high");
        return this;

    }
}
```

below is my stream processor to write temp. stats per minute to temp_stat_per_minute_topic kafka topic :

```
import com.mypackage.JsonDeserializer;
import com.mypackage.JsonSerializer;
import com.mypackage.WrapperSerde;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.WindowStore;

import java.util.Properties;

public class StreamProcessor {

    public  static void main(String... args){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "temp_stat_per_minute");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> tempPerSecStream = builder.stream("temperature_per_sec_topic");

        KTable<Windowed<String>, TemperatureStat> temperatureStatKTable = tempPerSecStream
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(60000L))
                .aggregate(() -> new TemperatureStat(),
                        (k, v, temp) -> { return temp.update(v);
                        },
                        Materialized.<String, TemperatureStat , WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("TemperatureStat_statestore")
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                                .withValueSerde(new TempStatSerde()));

        KStream<String, TemperatureStat > temperatureStatKStream = temperatureStatKTable
                .toStream()
                .selectKey((k, v) -> k.key());

        temperatureStatKStream.to("temp_stat_per_minute_topic ",Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new TempStatSerde()));

        Topology topology = builder.build();
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);

        System.out.println(topology.describe());

        streams.start();
    }

    static public final class TempStatSerde extends WrapperSerde<TemperatureStat> {
        public TempStatSerde() {
            super(new JsonSerializer<TemperatureStat>(), new JsonDeserializer<TemperatureStat>(TemperatureStat.class));
        }
    }

    static public final class TempSerde extends WrapperSerde<Temperature> {
        public TempSerde() {
            super(new JsonSerializer<Temperature>(), new JsonDeserializer<Temperature>(Temperature.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Below are my util classes :

1. JsonDeserializer :

   import com.google.gson.Gson;
   import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

   import java.util.Map;

   public class JsonDeserializer implements Deserializer {

   ```
   private Gson gson = new Gson();
   private Class<T> deserializedClass;

   public JsonDeserializer(Class<T> deserializedClass) {
       this.deserializedClass = deserializedClass;
   }

   public JsonDeserializer() {
   }

   @Override
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
       if(deserializedClass == null) {
           deserializedClass = (Class<T>) map.get("serializedClass");
       }
   }

   @Override
   public T deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
       if(bytes == null){
           return null;
       }

       return gson.fromJson(new String(bytes),deserializedClass);

   }

   @Override
   public void close() {

   }
   ```

   }

2.JsonSerializer :

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T t) {
        return gson.toJson(t).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

3.WrapperSerde :

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.util.Map;


public class WrapperSerde<T> implements Serde<T> {

    final private Serializer<T> serializer;
    final private Deserializer<T> deserializer;

    public WrapperSerde(Serializer<T> serializer, Deserializer<T> deserializer) {
        this.serializer = serializer;
        this.deserializer = deserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        serializer.configure(configs, isKey);
        deserializer.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        serializer.close();
        deserializer.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Serializer<T> serializer() {
        return serializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Deserializer<T> deserializer() {
        return deserializer;
    }
}
```

when running , i am getting following exception and not able to get desired ruslt. What am i doing wrong here , Please assist

```
[temp_stat_per_minute-f91817ab-14d5-4b4e-8fe0-8a4e425e1b47-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
22:49:12.915 [temp_stat_per_minute-f91817ab-14d5-4b4e-8fe0-8a4e425e1b47-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [temp_stat_per_minute-f91817ab-14d5-4b4e-8fe0-8a4e425e1b47] State transition from RUNNING to ERROR
22:49:12.915 [temp_stat_per_minute-f91817ab-14d5-4b4e-8fe0-8a4e425e1b47-StreamThread-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [temp_stat_per_minute-f91817ab-14d5-4b4e-8fe0-8a4e425e1b47] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
22:49:12.915 [temp_stat_per_minute-f91817ab-14d5-4b4e-8fe0-8a4e425e1b47-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [temp_stat_per_minute-f91817ab-14d5-4b4e-8fe0-8a4e425e1b47-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "temp_stat_per_minute-f91817ab-14d5-4b4e-8fe0-8a4e425e1b47-StreamThread-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:50)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:28)
    at org.rocksdb.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:17)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segment.openDB(Segment.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.Segments.getOrCreateSegment(Segments.java:91)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.put(RocksDBSegmentedBytesStore.java:100)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBWindowStore.put(RocksDBWindowStore.java:76)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.put(ChangeLoggingWindowBytesStore.java:34)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore$1.apply(CachingWindowStore.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:141)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:125)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.flush(CachingWindowStore.java:130)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.flush(MeteredWindowStore.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState(AbstractTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:406)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:380)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:368)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks$1.apply(AssignedTasks.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.applyToRunningTasks(AssignedTasks.java:362)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit(AssignedTasks.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll(TaskManager.java:401)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:1035)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:845)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.rocksdb.util.Environment.getJniLibraryName(Environment.java:41)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.<clinit>(NativeLibraryLoader.java:11)
    ... 29 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56244', transport: 'socket'
```

I am using kafka-streams version 2.0.0-cp1

Update : 
now i am getting below error after updating rocksdb

```
01:20:43.005 [temp_stat_per_minute-09dfb143-fab8-439e-bb15-9b9c6f30bbd4-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [temp_stat_per_minute-09dfb143-fab8-439e-bb15-9b9c6f30bbd4-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "temp_stat_per_minute-09dfb143-fab8-439e-bb15-9b9c6f30bbd4-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: task [1_0] Failed to flush state store TemperatureStat_statestore
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:242)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState(AbstractTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:406)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:380)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:368)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks$1.apply(AssignedTasks.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.applyToRunningTasks(AssignedTasks.java:362)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit(AssignedTasks.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll(TaskManager.java:401)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:1035)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:845)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [1_0] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key temp value com.TemperatureStat@1ede1095 timestamp 1556134799999) to topic temp_stat_per_minute_topic  due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
You can increase producer parameter `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` to avoid this error.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.recordSendError(RecordCollectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.access$500(RecordCollectorImpl.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1.onCompletion(RecordCollectorImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:890)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:816)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.ForwardingCacheFlushListener.apply(ForwardingCacheFlushListener.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.maybeForward(CachingWindowStore.java:114)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.access$300(CachingWindowStore.java:36)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore$1.apply(CachingWindowStore.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:141)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:125)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.flush(CachingWindowStore.java:130)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStore.flush(MeteredWindowStore.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:239)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It is not related to your code but to Rocksdb libraries. I had this problem on Windows and it helped me to add org.rocksdb/rocksdbjni as a dependency.

Comment: also i found this error above in logs before this rocksdb error :  ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl - task [0_0] Error sending record (key temp value com.TemperatureStat@2acd9a7f timestamp 1556092889103) to topic temp_stat_per_minute_topic  due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.; No more records will be sent and no more offsets will be recorded for this task.
You can increase producer parameter `retries` and `retry.backoff.ms` to avoid this error.

Comment: @KatyaGorshkova i have it in my pom as <dependency>
   <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
   <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: 3.5.1 is a kind of old. https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/3307 probably helps.

Comment: In the second stacktrace you get, it seems like you cannot connect to a broker during the flush of the state stores (see `ProcessorStateException` caused by `TimeoutException`). Have you checked your connection configuration? Checkout Stackoverflow for the `TimeoutException`. Some more information would be useful like: When does this error occur?  Has the Streams application run before?